# Как реализовать окно чата на CSS

Tags: html, css

Помогите сделать хвостик диалогового окна.
первый рис. - то, что сейчас есть;
второй рис. - тот хвостик, который надо сделать

[image: Окно которое сейчас есть]

[image: Окно, которое надо получить]

```
<section class="sreviews">
  <div class="clear"></div>
    <div class="clear"></div>
    <div class="from-them">
      <p>Текст</p>
    </div>
  </section>
```

```css
.sreviews {
  color: white;

  max-width: 800px;
  margin: 50px auto;
}
  .sreviews div {
    max-width: 400px;
    word-wrap: break-word;
    margin-bottom: 12px;
    line-height: 24px;
    &:after {
      content: "";
      display: table;
      clear: both;
    }
  }

.clear {clear: both}

.sreviews .from-me p{
  font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
  text-align: left;
  font-size: 18px;
}
.sreviews .from-them p{
  font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
  text-align: left;
  font-size: 18px;
}

.from-them {
  position:relative;
  padding:20px 25px;
  background:#FFFFFF;
  border-radius:25px;
  color: black;
  float: left;
  box-shadow: 0 0 10px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);


  &:before {
    content:"";
    position:absolute;
    z-index:2;
    bottom:-2px;
    left:-7px;
    height:20px;
    border-left:20px solid #E5E5EA;
    border-bottom-right-radius: 16px 14px;
    -webkit-transform:translate(0, -2px);
  }

  &:after {
    content:"";
    position:absolute;
    z-index:3;
    bottom:-2px;
    left:4px;
    width:26px;
    height:20px;
    background:white;
    border-bottom-right-radius: 10px;
    -webkit-transform:translate(-30px, -2px);
  }
}
```

Comment: а почему не svg?

Comment: Используй SVG внутрь которого вставляй свои сообщения

Comment: @dpi, на самом деле тут и без svg можно. По крайней мере, если фон не картинка.

Comment: @dpi, кстати, вставлять текст в svg - так себе идея - он же там переноситься не умеет. Я бы чисто стрелочку с кружочком на svg делал, а сообщение оставил div'ом.

Comment: @Qwertiy я бы сделал на svg  https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Element/foreignObject

Comment: @dpi, а для чата по ресурса не накладно foreignObject в каждом сообщении? Оно же вроде что-то типа полноценного вложенного документа создаёт? Кстати, а ещё не получится размер прямоугольника подогнать под размер foreignObject'а.

Comment: @Qwertiy я в принципе показал что можно внутрь SVG тулить стили, И делать уже что угодно с ними. Так изголяться над CSS мозгом можно тронуться хотя твой ответ вполне рабочий.

Comment: @dpi, я не в контексте своего ответа. Просто можно сделать обычный div c border-radius, а хвостик подложить на svg. Пожалуй, самое простое решение получится?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Вот, вроде хорошо получилось, но с размерами можно поиграться.

```css
div {
  float: left;
  background: silver;
  padding: 1em 1.5em;
  border-radius: 1em;
  position: relative;
  line-height: 1.5em;
}

div::after, div::before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  left: 100%;
  bottom: .5em;
  width: 1.8em;
  height: 1.8em;
  border: .5em solid white;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background: blue;
}

div::before {
  border-top: none;
  height: .9em;
  border-radius: 0 0 50% 50% / 0 0 100% 100%;
  background: silver;
  border-color: silver;
  margin-left: -.9em;
}
```

```html
<div>Just a message</div>
```

Comment: нельзя не плюсануть =)

Comment: @StrangerintheQ, я как раз заменил тень на сдвиг))

Comment: я попробовал что-то похожее с бордер радиусами городить но за 3 минуты не справился и появился этот ответ =)

Comment: @StrangerintheQ, а чего у автора так кода много? Мне что-то лень смотреть было. Сначала хотел в сниппет превратить, но потом увидел, что там scss.

Comment: я не смог понять, но попытка сделать хвост(after) там у внутреннего элемента

Comment: @StrangerintheQ, ну у меня белый круг непрозрачный. Не уверен, можно ли это под прозрачность адаптировать. Но в вопросе про неё ничего нет.